# NodeJS Microservices, combining data

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, microservices

I'm building a NodeJS platform that consist of several core 'parts' (users, messages and trading signals).

So my idea is to create microservices for each of them, and it works pretty well.. But I can't get my head around how to 'join' data between the microservices (I'm a frontender originally.....)

For example, I have 3 microservices.. Each with its own MongoDB, on its own machine complete isolated.. Imagine the common situation where the messages is retrieved from a single microservice, the message has a 'user_id' and I need to get the username and profilePicture to be combined in the retrieved message object..?

I read a lot about using Redis, but it seems like a 'messaging' service to me, not much of a 'combine' service.. Can anyone help me through the darkness??

Thanks!!

[image]

I know its a very general question... But I just can't get a grip of what the 'best practice' is when combining data of multiple micro services..

Comment: How can we advise you on your app, we have no idea what your code and your architecture look like...

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: This is still a very broad question... You want to "combine" stuff, but we don't know what you want to combine and in what way. BTW even frontend has services (look at Angular... :) A Node app is usually made by defining routes with Express, that call an API's endpoints.

Comment: Hmmm.. I know how routes etc work thats not the problem.. And calling a bunch of routes on every microservice can of course work (thats what I do now), but it will be very slow I presume.. ? Guess its my false assumption, but isn't a REST API no matter what underlying platform is used, the same principle?? Do I have to draw out what a message is , what a profile picture is and how a profile picture belongs to a message?

Comment: Sorry I don't know... This is a vast and complex topic, and Stackoverflow is intended for short code snippets and precise problems, not for debating architectural matters :/

Comment: Haha no problem.. But I can't believe Stack Overflow is only for asking what 1 + 1 is.. :) Isn't there a best practice or something for 'how to combine REST API's' output with microservices? Can't image its such un uncommon question

Comment: Well there are countless tutorials out there about how to make a NodeJS app. Come back when you want to know the answer to `1 + 1` ;)

Comment: I think you can have different aproaches for this one. One of them is making an API gateway, which is kind off a entrypoint for all your microservices. 

Every request you get should do to your API gateway, and the gateway will then further it to the microservice.

So you get your request in you API GW, it calls the different microservices ( async if the data from the different services don't interact with each other), and then combines them in the response and sends it back. example: https://cdn.wp.nginx.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Richardson-microservices-part2-3_api-gateway.png

Comment: Thanks @TanguyB! That seams pretty straightforward to implement. And a public API can possibly handle authentication also I presume, makes it better.. Just wondering if NodeJS is a good fit as Public API / Gateway.. Its to bloated to use only for handling request and merging results I guess.. BTW can you make a real post of it? So I can vote it as answer later on :)

Comment: Well, what I did was making an Authentication Microservice, which provided me a JWT. & handled auth. Your API gateway can then confirm every request with the Auth. microservice. You can make your API gateway as broad as you want, and I think any language can fit the picture, as long as you do it safely & secure.

Comment: do you want to combine data received by some of the microservices and perform some operations on it ?

Comment: @marvel308, yes I do! For some clients I need to combine data returned from multiple microservices.. I have setup a API Gateway with NodeJS. So far this tutorial really helps: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/02/22/mean-with-angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial#authentication-service-ts.

Comment: You can do this by maintaining a separate "read-model" data store, which is optimised for your UI ViewModels. Your read model would subscribe to events from the other services in order to keep its data current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this can be done using [kafka streams](https://www.confluent.io/blog/distributed-real-time-joins-and-aggregations-on-user-activity-events-using-kafka-streams/), it is a pub/sub model where you can join streams based on a common key. You can either subscribe to a topic or add a data transformation service which joins multiple streams and pushes the joined/transformed data into a new stream. All services who wants to use this data can subscribe to this new stream. I recommend you go through this [link](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/)

Comment: Interesting one! I like the idea of streams instead of manually combining the data of multiple REST api's in the Gateway... Thanks I will try it out